# Async unit testing with portable class libraries

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, portable-class-library

I have a portable class library that needs to target at least .net 4.5 and Silverlight 5. I'm running into an issue trying to write MSTest unit tests in VS 2012 because my library does not use the new async/await paradigm. Is there any way I can test this method?

```
public static void Get(string uri, string acceptHeader, Action<string> callback)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Accept = acceptHeader;        

    request.BeginGetResponse(o =>
    {
        var r = o.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        try
        {
            var response = r.EndGetResponse(o);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                callback(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new WebException(string.Format("Unable to access {0}", uri), ex);
        }
    }, request);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend you reconsider `async`/`await`. It's the wave of the future. [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) provides `async` support to portable libraries targeting .NET 4.5 and SL5.

But if you don't want to do that, you can still use `async` unit tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Get_RetrievesExpectedString()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  var client = new ... // arrange

  client.Get(uri, acceptHeader, result =>
  {
    tcs.SetResult(result);
  });
  var actual = await tcs.Task;

  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Or if you want, you can do it "old-school":

```
[TestMethod]
public void Get_RetrievesExpectedString()
{
  var mre = new ManualResetEvent(initialState: false);
  string actual = null;
  var client = new ... // arrange

  client.Get(uri, acceptHeader, result =>
  {
    actual = result;
    mre.Set();
  });
  mre.WaitOne();

  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: I am actually open to using async/await, but the *Async methods seem to be missing on `HttpWebRequest` for PCL. How would you change my `Get` method?

Comment: Task.Factory.FromAsync is for converting APM into async/await.

Comment: And in this conversion the "right" way to do it would be to have the method return the string that I'm sending into the callback right?

Comment: No...The correct way to do it is to have the Get method return an awaitable Task<string>, have the calling await the Get. Then instead of feeding in a callback you just invoke what you need in the calling code.

Comment: @user140550: If your `Get` method is an `async Task<string>` method, then it can just return the string.

Answer (score 2):

Just can't resist refactoring the code. You can use closure to do the following

```
public static void Get(string uri, string acceptHeader, Action<string> callback)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Accept = acceptHeader;        

    request.BeginGetResponse(o =>
    {
        try
        {
            var response = request.EndGetResponse(o);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                callback(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new WebException(string.Format("Unable to access {0}", uri), ex);
        }
    }, null);
}
```

However at the end of the day you can just do the following

```
public async static void Get(string uri, string acceptHeader, Action<string> callback)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Accept = acceptHeader;        
    var response = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                             request.BeginGetRequestStream ,
                             request.EndGetRequestStream ,
                             uri,
                             null);
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response))
    {
        callback(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Okay so here is how I would do it

```
void Main()
{
    {...}
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Accept = acceptHeader;
    var response = await request.DownloadStringTaskAwait();
    DoSomeStuff(response);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class HttpWebRequestExtension
{
    public async Task<string> DownloadStringTaskAwait(this HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        var response = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(
                            request.BeginGetRequestStream,
                            request.EndGetRequestStream,
                            null);
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response))
                    {
                         return sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
            }

}
```

Comment: Your method compiles as a PCL?

Comment: And thanks for the refactoring. Originally the callback was a separate method, hence the cruft.

Comment: You should avoid `async void`. In this case, it messes with your error handling if a download ever fails.

Comment: Actually the error handling was messed up before. The throw was on the wrong thread. But yes, fair enough. You do want to use async Task instead, but that will permeate your whole code.

Comment: Yes, and it's still messed up now.

Comment: I appreciate all the help Aron and Stephen (seriously!) but does your latest code compile? Resharper says ambiguous invocation and compile fails.

Comment: BAHHH that old chestnut again... have to replace the request.EndGetResponse to x => request.EndGetResponse(x)...

Comment: That or explicite give the return type on the Async...It can't figure out if it was a function or an action.